# Can't get multiple values for css property JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm having a problem with setting multiple values on the same css property in Javascript. The problem is that I can't make it so both of the properties get rendered but instead the last line gets executed.

```
//Map is a variable linked to an element
map.style.cssText = "transform: rotate(90deg); transform: translate(-50%, -50%);";
```

Comment: think what happens if you did `color:red; color: blue` - the same applies to `transform` - `"transform: rotate(90deg) translate(-50%, -50%);"` would work - or `map.style.transform="rotate(90deg) translate(-50%, -50%)"`

Comment: changing `transform: rotate(90deg); transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` to `transform: rotate(90deg) translate(-50%, -50%);` should fix this  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it this way:

```js
temp0.style.cssText = "transform: rotate(90deg) translate(-50%, -50%);"
```

That's because the cssText property works like inline style, and the last occurrence of a property overrides all previous ones.

Comment: why do you need to have the value twice like that?

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake

Answer (score 0):

Pls, Hover this div.

```css
div {height: 100px; width:100px; background:yellow; border: 1px solid #000;}
div:hover {transform: translate(100px, 100px) rotate(45deg);}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Also, CSS uses the single-priority rule, which means - after page-rendering all your CSS is combined and converted to `CSS Object Model`. And, for each selector - the most prioratized CSS is set and others are overwritten, so for same selector and same CSS-Property: You will have 1 single resultant Value.